# Convert Objective-C to Swift - what to use for unsigned type?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a problem when I tried to convert Objective-C code to Swift.
Here are my codes in Objective-C:

```
NSMutableData *deviceToken = [NSMutableData data];
unsigned value;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:self.deviceToken];
while(![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    [scanner scanHexInt:&value];
    value = htonl(value);
    [deviceToken appendBytes:&value length:sizeof(value)];
}
```

my code in Swift

```
let deviceToken = NSMutableData()
    var value: CUnsignedInt
    let scanner = NSScanner(string: deviceTokenString)
    while (!scanner.atEnd) {
        scanner.scanHexInt(&value)
    }
```

I don't know what type unsigned in Swift and how to convert them.

Comment: have you tried UInt?

Comment: UInt32 seems to be the correct type. `func scanHexInt(_ result: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>) -> Bool`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is working, the only error you´re getting with the code snippet that you have pasted is "Address of variable "value" taken before it is initialized" which means that you haven´t assign a value to the variable yet.

For example `var value: CUnsignedInt = 10` will remove the error. If you´re getting other errors you need to provide more code.